# gRPC binary is not loading

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

When am starting my network am getting following error:

```
Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: node-v83-linux-x64-glibc
Found: [node-v64-linux-x64-glibc]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
```

I tried the recommend comand `npm rebuild` but I still have the same error.

I completely removed everything and reinstalled it - but still the same error.

```
which npm
```

/usr/bin/npm

```
which node
```

/usr/bin/node

node version: v14.15.4

npm version: 6.14.10

Update/more Information:
I am using hyperledger fabric vers 2 and fabric sdk nodes.
[This](https://github.com/DOBEN/Showcase_of_blockchain_interoperability_in_the_field_of_supply_chain) is the repo am studying

Comment: To solve this, we need more information about what network was started and what command occurred when we entered it.

Comment: If it is fabric-sdk-node, try lowering it to version 12 (12.13.1 and higher), not node 14 version. [fabric-sdk-node](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node)

Comment: I updated the information. I tried to lower the version to 12.20.1 but am facing the same  error

Comment: Did you properly clean everything before installation? (node_modules and cache clean, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't remove the cache. So I deleted everything again and installed Node version 12.20.1 . Same error appeared again. Afterwards I tried `npm rebuild` but still same error.

Comment: try to use `strace`, it will show you what the process is trying to do, and hopefully you will find out what directories it is looking at.

Answer (score 0):

> Module version 83 corresponds to Node 14, not 13. Unfortunately, it
> have not yet published binaries for Node 14, so it's going to be
> difficult to get that working

else you can use Node 12

Full answer - https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1460#issuecomment-638965479

Comment: I have now installed node v12.20.1 and npm 6.14.10 but am still facing the same error

Comment: try npm rebuild

Comment: It also doesn't work with this version. Still same error...